# anaconda command prompt help required

Tags: python, anaconda

I started running one python code in anaconda command prompt. Now that python code is running from last two days. Till now it has computed value for 2800 items and there are 8000 more values to compute. I want to get out of that loop and I want that computed data of 2800 values to be safe. How can i get out of that loop( terminate that loop),not whole code, without the loss of that data? my code is still running and computing values.

`
#

Database = np.zeros(10000*72).reshape(10000,72)

for entry in range(10000):

```
    Database[entry] = hist
    print("Entered for !"+imagename)
```

collection = client.test_database.coraltest29
collection.insert({"distances":Database.tolist(),"name":'Coral Dataset'})`

Comment: You can't if its read to a variable list or dict. Try to use multiprocessing next time to split the load over multiple "workers'.. a.k.a. processors. It now runs a serial process and not parallel.

Comment: Posting your program code or outline would help as well to assist you in finding a better solution than I just gave based on internal memory `variables`.

Answer (score 0):

Probably if you do CTRL-C it'll stop running.  About your data, your output it'll be still there, and if you created any log text file it's going to be there for sure.

Comment: I want to get out of loop and want my program to do computation that are outside of that loop. In simple words I want to terminate that loop, not whole code.

Comment: You'd need to add a break, but you can't change the code while is running... so I'm sorry I don't see a solution here, let's see if somebody answers with a better option